# Add quotation marks to URL when redirecting with GET method

Tags: html, forms, get

I have a search form looking like this:

```
<form action='http://localhost:1000/' method='GET'>
   <input name="searchTerm" type="search">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Let's say, I search for the word **test**, the search form will redirect me to: http://localhost:1000/?searchTerm=test.

Instead, I would like to wrap quotation marks around the search term - in this case **test**, just like this: [http://localhost:1000/?searchTerm="test"](http://localhost:1000/?searchTerm=%22test%22).

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Comment: Why? If you need quotes around the value, it almost certainly makes more sense to add them in the server side code.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Because I want to redirect to an external result page that is using search terms while putting them in between quotation marks. If I don't add quotation marks, I won't redirect correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a JS function. Code looks as follows:

**Form**

```
<form onsubmit="return redirect(this)">
   <input id="searchvalue">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**JS function**

```
 <script> 
  function redirect(that) {
  window.location.href = 'http://localhost:1000/' + '?searchTerm=' + '"' + (document.getElementById('searchvalue').value) + '"' 
  return false;
  }
 </script>
```